# How can I randomly move a ball on a canvas in Python?

Tags: python, canvas, random, tkinter

I created a little 'game' but I have some problems.

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/XkSvLAHS

So, there is a ball that should move randomly on the canvas but I don't now how to do this. 
I have this:

```
def move_ball_right_down(): 
    global x, y, dx, dy 

    x, y = x + dx, y + dy 

    can.coords(ball, x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r) 

def move_ball_left_up(): 
    global x, y, dx, dy 

    x, y = x - dx, y - dy 

    can.coords(ball, x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r)
```

But with this, the ball only goes from one corner to an other but it should move randomly.

I have an other problem with this:

```
def click_ball(event): 
    global x, y, points, ball, r, dx, flag 

    if flag == 1 and\ 
    event.x <= x + r and event.x >= x - r and\ 
    event.y <= y + r and event.y >= y - r:
```

These lines suppose to detect the ball, so when I click on that I get a point but it selects not just the ball, but a square around it and I'm sure there is a better way to detect the ball. How should I do?

Comment: You haven't shown us the code that assigns values to `dx` and `dy` - that's what decides where the ball moves, and that's where your first problem is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe why did you put my topic on hold? I think Brionius' answer is not too long and the answer is correct and helpful.
I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, why not just randomize x and y, and forget about `dx` and `dy`?

```
def move_ball_right_down(): 
    global x, y

    x, y = randrange(0, 400), randrange(0, 400)  # Randomize x and y (note that you should substitute your max and min canvas coordinate values if you want the ball to stay in view.

    can.coords(ball, x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r)
```

As for your second question, if you want the user to have to click on the ball itself, and not anywhere on the bounding rectangle, change that last `if` statement to this:

```
if flag == 1 and ((event.x-x)**2 + (event.y-y)**2) <= r**2:
```

That's essentially the pythagorean formula indicating that the distance between the points (event.x, event.y) and (x,y) is less than or equal to r.

Comment: Full code of the game is in the post, if it helps you. x, y = 250, 250
dx, dy = 10, 10
r = 20
flag = 0
moving = True

Comment: Ah, I missed that.  Added to my answer.